# Substring from certain text until the following newline

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have for the example text in a column:

```
"name : A
Street : B
Country : Country_name
Zip Code : 12345

Send the package to this address"
```

How to extract only the text "Country_name".
I can't use `charindex` "zip code" because it's not shown in all times and the text is dynamic.

How do I `charindex` the newline?

Comment: Best long-term solution is to revise the process inserting this data so fields are stored properly separated as columns. T-SQL's string handling facilities are very limited, as is the opportunity for giving clear feedback if the format doesn't match. Having said that, a newline is `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`, so you can `CHARINDEX` that as  the end.

Comment: but how do i find the newline in the correct postion? i know how to use charindex and char(13) &char(10)

Comment: The correct position is the newline after you find `Country`, so limit the string to that first (e.g. `STUFF(@s, 1, CHARINDEX('Country : ', @s) + LEN('Country : '), '')`). The whole thing is messy, if `STRING_SPLIT` is available to you (2016+) you can consider using that as well, e.g. `SELECT STUFF([value] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, 1, LEN(' Country : '), '') FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@s  COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), CHAR(0)), CHAR(0))  WHERE [value] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT LIKE 'Country : %'`. Even this contains advanced magic to do "safe" multi-character splitting.

Comment: it's don't work, i'm working with sql server 2014

Comment: Find a string splitting function that works with your version (an easy search), split on the CR/LF characters and then filter for those rows that start with "Country: "

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).